# best E-Commerce Shopping Carts for Zend Framework developer

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, e-commerce, shopping-cart

What is the easiest, most friendly and robust E-Commerce Shopping Carts for a Zend Framework developer. I want invest my time in something forward-looking. I'm also interested in a solution with a big tutorial base. It should be free.

I found this solutions for PHP/MySQL :

- Magento Commerce
- Opencart
- PrestaShop
- OsCommerce
- Zen Cart
- Digistore
- CREloaded
- Zeuscart
- ShopperPress

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i vote for magento, because its is based on zend libraries and the it's team has also behind some development of zend libraries.

Answer (score 16):

You may also try to write your own cart in Zend Framework which which will exactly suit your needs.

[Storefront](http://code.google.com/p/zendframeworkstorefront/) from the book [Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development](https://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-1-8-web-application-development/book) may be a good example.

Comment: +1 well you are right, i will prefer it.

Comment: The team actually agreed on this solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to recommend Magento. Read this page for more information on the relationship between Magento Commerce and the Zend Framework.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/magento-zend