# Is there a way to create an ecommerce site using zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, e-commerce

The title might be a bit misleading. As you can see, we created a site for a client. Afterwards, he decided to add ecommerce-like module wherein the user's may avail items from the site. This was not the main intention of the site but the client doesn't want a new one but rather, update the site and add an ecommerce feature.

We are planning to do it manually... I was just thinking if there's a better way of doing it? are there any tools or plugin code or way that we can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

[best E-Commerce Shopping Carts for Zend Framework developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032782/best-e-commerce-shopping-carts-for-zend-framework-developer)

Always good to give SO a search.

You may also like to look at 
http://ecartcommerce.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ecommerce site magento

Here is a link for

http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Comment: thanks, but yes, magento was our first target but as you can see, the products must be integrated on the site itself.

Comment: I've looked ant Magento in the past and wonder whether this is a suitable option for a smaller project?  Interested to know what others think.

Comment: A small standard shop is set up fast in magento, but if you want to customize it, it requires a lot of work to get into it.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on zend framework 2 e commerce module if anyone interested then please follow on github
https://github.com/indpurvesh/mage2